# rails radio button tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I need a help. i have form tag button in array quiz option. I need to checked true answer when value answer is 1.

```
<%= radio_button_tag('quiz_en_option[is_answer][]',"1",quiz_option_en.is_answer) %>True 
<!-- <input id="quiz_en_option_is_answer__1" type="radio" value="1" name="quiz_en_option[is_answer][]" checked="checked"> -->
```

help me please

Answer (score 0):

[radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag)

```
# if quiz_option_en.is_answer is 1 it will get checked else unchecked 
<%= radio_button_tag('quiz_en_option[is_answer][]',"1",quiz_option_en.is_answer.eql?(1) %>True
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but It doesn't work, I get checked still in first radio button even I choose second radio button. #sorry, if my english isn't good

Comment: what _quiz_option_en.is_answer_ returns?

Comment: quiz_option_en.is_answer return 1

Comment: what type(boolean,int,string)  of column is _is_answer_ ?

Answer (score 0):

I get true answer now, name should be not array.

```
  <%= radio_button_tag('quiz_en_option[is_answer]', i.to_s, quiz_option_en.is_answer, id: "answer_" + i.to_s, class: "en-answer-radio" ) %>True
```